# jQuery selecting right DOM element

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

**Live example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/KezWE/

I have a few sets of unordered lists (menu + product list).

My sorting script works fine, but when I try to insert two lists at one page - they are not working as separate lists and are being both sorted. And I don't want that, I want one menu to sort only the first list below, not both of them.

I've been trying hard with (this).next() etc., but nothing helps. I'm unable to change the DOM, can only edit jQuery code.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a data-value="all" href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a data-value="big" href="#">Big</a></li>
    <li><a data-value="small" href="#">Small</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li><div data-value="big">BIG</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="small">SMALL</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="big">BIG</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="small">SMALL</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="big">BIG</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="big">BIG</div></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu">
    <li><a data-value="all" href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a data-value="big" href="#">Big</a></li>
    <li><a data-value="small" href="#">Small</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li><div data-value="big">BIG</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="small">SMALL</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="big">BIG</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="small">SMALL</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="big">BIG</div></li>
    <li><div data-value="big">BIG</div></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('ul.menu li a[data-value=all]').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('.list li div').show();
                e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery('ul.menu li a[data-value=big]').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('.list li div').show(); //I know this looks just BAD, but that's just for jsfiddle
    jQuery('.list li div[data-value=small]').hide();
                e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery('ul.menu li a[data-value=small]').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('.list li div').show(); //I know this looks just BAD, but that's just for jsfiddle
    jQuery('.list li div[data-value=big]').hide();
                e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Live example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/KezWE/

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the result you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/KezWE/4/

Let me know!

Comment: works amazing! Can you help me anyways with the original code? My JS is much more complicated and I'd love to use your solution, but if there's a way of making the old code from the first post work - it'd be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Can you give your ul's a unique id and reference them explicitly - using ".menu" will affect both menus - that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I can't, menus are generated automatically so IDs are not welcome. I was thinking about doing something like jQuery(this).next('list li div'), but it doesn't work for me. Not sure why, but maybe because of nested link?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('ul.menu li a[data-value=all]').click(function(e) {
    var list = jQuery(this).closest('ul').next('.list');
    list.find('div').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery('ul.menu li a[data-value=big]').click(function(e) {
    var list = jQuery(this).closest('ul').next('.list');
    list.find('div').show();
    list.find('div[data-value=small]').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery('ul.menu li a[data-value=small]').click(function(e) {
    var list = jQuery(this).closest('ul').next('.list');
    list.find('div').show();
    list.find('div[data-value=big]').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```